# Enzyme instance() returns null

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test:

```
describe('Form', () => {
  let store;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(mockData);
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Form />
      </Provider>
    );
  });

  it('handleForm calls uses validate() for validation', () => {
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    const submitFormButton = wrapper.find('.submitFormButton');
    submitFormButton.simulate('click');
    console.log(instance); // null
  });
});
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong exactly?

I know that Enzyme has this thing:

> NOTE: With React 16 and above, instance() returns null for stateless
>   functional components.

but my functional component does have a state, I'm using hooks (if that changes anything) and there should be some way to access `instance.componentMethod()` still, right?

Comment: does moving `store` and `wrapper` initialization to `it` function scope will trigger it to work?

Comment: @Qiarash no, it's the same thing, `wrapper` works just fine in the `it` block, just not the instance of it.

Comment: What do you mean "my functional component does have a state"? Are you saying the redux store? If so, the redux store is attached to the component props. Only the class-based component has `state` property.

Comment: @slideshowp2 i mean I'm using `useState` and for redux I use `useSelector` hook so no, Redux store is not coming from props.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: With React 16 and above, instance() returns null for stateless functional components.

With `stateless component` they mean actually here functional components. The `instance()` method is reserved for the class based component.

So you can use it for this component:

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

But not for this one:

```js
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```