# How to test form submit with jest and enzyme in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am learning reactjs form with hooks, now I would like to test form on submit using jest and enzyme.

here is my login component.

```
import React from 'react'

function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // ....api calLS
    }
    return (
        <div>
             <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login">
    
            <input type="email" id="email-input" name="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        
            <input type="password" id="password-input" name="password" value={password} onChange={e =>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Here is the login.test.js file

```
 describe('my sweet test', () => {
    it('clicks it', () => {
      
       const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
       const updatedEmailInput = simulateChangeOnInput(wrapper, 'input#email-input', 'blah@gmail.com')
       const updatedPasswordInput = simulateChangeOnInput(wrapper, 'input#password-input', 'death'); 

       expect(updatedEmailInput.props().value).toEqual('blah@gmail.com');
       expect(updatedPasswordInput.props().value).toEqual('death');

       const instance = wrapper.instance()
       const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleSubmit')
   
       instance.forceUpdate();    
   
       const submitBtn = app.find('#sign-in')
       submitBtn.simulate('click')
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()

    })
    
  })
```

Unfortunately when I run `npm test` I get the following error.
[image]

What do I need to do to solve this error or can someone provide a tutorial on how to test a form submit?

Comment: MO the problem is you should not be testing handleSubmit but rather your API calls. You can spy on that method instead and your test should expect that it is called with the appropriate params.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the documentation it's said that you cant use shallow.instance() for functional components
It will return null: https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html
There was also a previous answer on this topik
[Enzyme instance() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561427/enzyme-instance-returns-null)

You can pass validated function handleSubmit to Login as a prop like there [How to use jest.spyOn with React function component using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297482/how-to-use-jest-spyon-with-react-function-component-using-typescript)

```
 // Unit test
  describe('SomeComponent' () => {
  it('validates model on button click', () => {
      const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
      const wrapper = mount(
          <Login handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
      );
      const instance = wrapper.instance();
      const submitBtn = app.find('#sign-in')
      submitBtn.simulate('click')
      expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }
```

You need to call this test function handleSubmit in your login component either as a part of onSubmit or export whole onSubmit from upper components. Example login code with importing part of login function

```
import React from 'react'

function Login( {handleSubmit}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        if (handleSubmit) {
          handleSubmit()
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        // ....api calLS
    }
    return (
        <div>
             <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="login">
    
            <input type="email" id="email-input" name="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        
            <input type="password" id="password-input" name="password" value={password} onChange={e =>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Example login code with importing of submit function

```
import React from 'react'

function Login( {handleSubmit}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   
    // handleSubmit is imported with props
 
    return (
        <div>
             <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login">
    
            <input type="email" id="email-input" name="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        
            <input type="password" id="password-input" name="password" value={password} onChange={e =>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: so what do I need to do to test my form submit ?

Comment: You can pass validated function as props like there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297482/how-to-use-jest-spyon-with-react-function-component-using-typescript

Comment: You need to use this test handleSubmit function in Login component

Comment: May use toHaveBeenCalled without times